# How do I extract parts using egrep

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I am looking to extract a few things from a line of data:

> **bin-66-776-33-22.hero.com** - - [**17/oct/2012:04:16:12** +0100] "GET **/intro.txt** http/1.0" **200 25** "-" "hero/2.1 (+http://hero.com/intro.html

The bits in bold are the parts I would like to extract

I have currently been using

```
cat file.txt | egrep "^(.*) - .* \[(.*)12"
```

However, I am knew to this and cant really see how its working and the end bit `'(.*)12'` looks at too much stuff.

I was also wondering whether this would be better in a bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is better suited for this:

```
$ awk -F'[[ ]' '{print $1,$5,$8,$10,$11}' file
bin-66-776-33-22.hero.com 17/oct/2012:04:16:12 /intro.txt 200 25
```

Comment: Thanks but just not what I was looking for, the bits in bold are the ones I want to extract, your misses out a few things, but thanks anyway i'll see what I can do with awk

Comment: I must have added an extra space in the input file originally which shifted the columns by 1. The columns you want are `1,5,8,10,11` http://ideone.com/Kngw2d

Comment: Is there no way of doing a regular expression? Using Bash?

Comment: @user2160949 yes of course, a simple search would have told you that. This is a field separation problem and `awk` is the perfect tool for it, don't force a solution using tools there aren't design for the job.

Comment: @user2160949 you should accept this answer to let people know your question is solved. You do this by clicking the tick mark new to the answer.